# Spring mvc character encoding in jboss linux

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, encoding

I send this query string in my windows tomcat

/app/search/?destinationName=Canc%C3%BAn%2CMexico

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = { RequestMethod.GET, 
                                                RequestMethod.POST  })
    public String search(
     @RequestParam(value = "destinationName", required = false) String 
                  destinationName,
     BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) throws     
                          IOException,ParseException {
```

a break point at the controller in windows tomcat will show this:
Cancún, Mexico

a break point at the controller in linux jboss will show this:
CancÃºn, mexico

I have tried:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean utfFilter() {         CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new 
CharacterEncodingFilter();
filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new 
FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setFilter(filter);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

but that has not fixed the encoding problem at jboss linux

any hint?

Answer (score 0):

for my jboss red hat 6.4 problem fixed by adding this to standalone.xml

```
<system-properties>
    <!-- URI Properties -->
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING"         value="UTF-8"/>
        <property     name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING"         value="true"/>
    </system-properties>
```

hint taken from:
https://developer.jboss.org/message/643825#643825